# How to assign minimum value based on lookup values in two other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

***Objective:*** Looking to programmatically match combinations in two columns to find the lowest value of another column

Let's say I have this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Part_1': [91, 201, 201],
     'Part_2': [201,111,91], 
     'Result': [3,3, 3], 
     'Sub-Score': [0.60, 0.8,0.9], 
     'Final-Score': [0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to to find the minimum value from the sub-score column that can be assigned to the Final-Score column. I need to choose based on matching Part_1 and Part_2 (which can be in different positions for either part):

```
d_new = {'Part_1': [91, 201, 201],
         'Part_2': [201,111,91], 
         'Result': [3,3, 3], 
         'Sub-Score': [0.60, 0.8,0.9], 
         'Final-Score': [0.6,.8,.6]}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=d_new)
df_new
```

Here we can see that **row 0** and **row 2** have the *same values* in columns **Part_1** and **Part_2**, they are simply out of order. Further, we can see **row 0** has a Sub-Score value of 0.60 and **row 2** has a Sub-Score value of 0.9.

I am looking to assign the Sub-Score value from **row 0** (since it is the lowest of **row 0** and **row 2**) to the column Final-Score for both row 0 and **row 2**. **Row 1** has nothing to compare to and does not have the same parts as **row 0** and **row 2**, so we carry over its Sub-score value to the Final-Score value.

Any help would be appreciated.

**(Edited):**

Input:

```
   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score
0            0      91     201       3        0.6
1            0     201     111       3        0.8
2            0     201      91       3        0.9
```

Desired output:

```
   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score
0          0.6      91     201       3        0.6
1          0.8     201     111       3        0.8
2          0.6     201      91       3        0.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the values, then groupby based on the ngroup and transform min i.e

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.sort(df[['Part_1','Part_2']]))
grps = temp.groupby(temp.columns.tolist()).ngroup()

df['new']=df.groupby(grps)['Sub-Score'].transform('min')

   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score  new
0            0      91     201       3        0.6  0.6
1            0     201     111       3        0.8  0.8
2            0     201      91       3        0.9  0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a (somewhat hacky) way that seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Part_1': [91, 201, 201],
     'Part_2': [201, 111, 91],
     'Result': [3, 3, 3],
     'Sub-Score': [0.60, 0.8, 0.9],
     'Final-Score': [0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Find lowest part-number of part-pair and add as new column
df["min_part"] = df[["Part_1", "Part_2"]].min(axis=1)
# Find highest part-number of part-pair and add as new column
df["max_part"] = df[["Part_1", "Part_2"]].max(axis=1)
print df
```

The data set now looks like:

```
   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score  min_part  max_part
0            0      91     201       3        0.6        91       201
1            0     201     111       3        0.8       111       201
2            0     201      91       3        0.9        91       201
```

Then do:

```
# Group together rows with the same min_part, max_part pair, and assign
# their lowest "Sub-Score" value to the "Final-score" column
df["Final-Score"] = df.groupby(["min_part", "max_part"])["Sub-Score"].transform("min")
print df
```

Final result:

```
   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score  min_part  max_part
0          0.6      91     201       3        0.6        91       201
1          0.8     201     111       3        0.8       111       201
2          0.6     201      91       3        0.9        91       201
```

Optionally, keep only the original columns:

```
df = df[["Final-Score", "Part_1", "Part_2", "Result", "Sub-Score"]]
print df
```

Result:

```
   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score
0          0.6      91     201       3        0.6
1          0.8     201     111       3        0.8
2          0.6     201      91       3        0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would go over a temporary table. First generate a key, then groupby that key and apply min():

```
# Generate a key that does not depend 
# on the order of the values in Part_1 and Part_2
df['key'] = [str(set(i)) for i in list(df[['Part_1', 'Part_2']].values)]

# Generate temporary table that contains keys and minimal values
tmp = df.groupby('key').min()['Sub-Score']

scores = {}    
for key, val in zip(tmp.index, tmp.values):
    scores[key] = val

# Place the minimal values in the original table
df.loc[:, 'Final-Score'] = [scores[key] for key in df.key]

# Finally, delete what you don't need
del df['key'], tmp

df
>   Final-Score  Part_1  Part_2  Result  Sub-Score
>0          0.6      91     201       3        0.6
>1          0.8     201     111       3        0.8
>2          0.6     201      91       3        0.9
```